# Creating Method to Reference Parent Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, parent-child, parent, backtrace

So I had asked a question similar to this, but I don't think the answer I got worked with what I was trying to do.

Say I have this class:

**Java Code**

```
public class Section
{
    private String sDocumentTitle;
    private String sHeadingTitle;
    private String sText;
    public ArrayList<Section> aSiblingSection = new ArrayList<Section>();
    public ArrayList<Section> aChildSection = new ArrayList<Section>();
    public ArrayList<image> aImages = new ArrayList<image>();

    public void setName(String docTitle)
    {
        //set passed parameter as name
        sDocumentTitle = docTitle;
    }

    public void addName (String docTitle)
    {
        //adds remaining Title String together
        sDocumentTitle += (" " + docTitle);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        //return the set name
        return sDocumentTitle;
    }

    public void setSection(String section)
    {
        //set passed parameter as name
        sHeadingTitle = section;
    }

    public void addSection(String section)
    {
        //adds section parts together
        sHeadingTitle += ("" + section);
    }

    public String getSection()
    {
        //return the set name
        return sHeadingTitle;
    }
    public void setText(String text)
    {
        //set passed parameter as name
        sText = text;
    }

    public void addText(String text)
    {
        //adds 
        sText += (" " + text);
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        //return the set name
        return sText;
    }
    public ArrayList getChildSection()
    {
        return aChildSection;
    }
}
```

And a child section initialized in this manner in a driver class...

```
Section aSection = new Section();
aMainSection.get(0).aChildSection.add(aSection);
```

Essentially, could someone give me an idea of how I would I add a method in the section class which returns the parents from an array list of 'aChildSection'?

Comment: Where is 'aMainSection` defined?

Comment: aMainSection is just the name of a 'section' initialized in the driver class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constructor

```
private final Section parent;
public Section(Section parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public Section getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```

When you add a child

```
Section aSection = new Section(aMainSection.get(0));
aMainSection.get(0).aChildSection.add(aSection);
```

Comment: When I tried to implement this code, everything seemed fine in the Section class. But in my driver, every instance of `Section aSection = new Section();` returned a compiler error.

Comment: I assumed you wanted every `Section` to have a parent, if you want some Sections without a parent you can add an empty constructor which sets the `parent` to `null`.

Comment: SO just something like `public Section()
    {
     this.parent = null;
    }`?

Answer (score 2):

With your model, you can't. Add a parent section:

```
private Section parent;
```

and set that for every child session (it will be null in the parent session)

Answer (score 2):

I guess, each section (except the main section) has **one** parent. The trick is, that a section needs to know it's parent section.

A widely used pattern is to set the parent with the constructor and add some logic to the constructor so that it will register the section as parent's child automatically:

```
public Section(Section parent) {
  this.parent = parent;   // remember your parent
  parent.addChild(this);  // register yourself as your parent's child
}
```

Then use this code to add a section:

```
Section mainSection = aMainSection.get(0);   // ugly!!
Section section = new Section(mainSection);
```

*Refactoring tip* - declare all your fields *private* and implement getters. Even better if those getters don't return the internal lists but just values from the list.

Comment: @Andreas_D What is `parent.addChild(this)` supposed to be? Is that another method I should create?

Comment: @This - yes, that was the message. A section should have a method to have a child added.